# start and end shellscript for multiple programs

Tags: bash, shell

Following problem:

3 programs:

- one Java application which is started via a existing sh script
- one node application
- one grunt server

I want to write 2 shell scripts, the first should start all 3 programs. The second should end them. For the first script I simply call the starting commands. But for the second, which should be a standalone script(as the first should be), I have to know all process Ids for killing them. But even if I know these Ids, what if they started sub processes. I would just kill these parent processes, wouldn't I?

What's the approach here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `pkill -P -KILL [parentid]`. This should kill processes with the designated parent ID.